# Getiing error during email send process

Tags: 7, emails

I am using [PepiPost](http://pepipost.com) mail service for sending an email. PepiPost mail service provides an [SDK](https://github.com/pepipost/pepipost-sdk-php) for send sending mail. They provided a sample code for sending mail.

When I send the mail getting the following error message:

> Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem
>   persists.

But mail is sent to the corresponding user and user can receive the mail.

I have created a Custom mail system call by implementing 
**MailSystemInterface**. The code is available in the [here](https://github.com/pepipost/pepipost-sdk-php). Although this is the code I placed in `mail()`  function.

```
class TestMailSystem implements MailSystemInterface {
  require_once __DIR__.'/includes/vendor/autoload.php';

  use PepipostAPIV10Lib\Controllers\Email;


  public function format(array $message) {
    // Join message array.
    $message['body'] = implode("\n\n", $message['body']);
    return $message;
  }

public function mail(array $message) {


$email = new Email();

$data = array(
      'api_key'   =>  '************',
      'recipients'    =>  $message['to'],
      'email_details' => array(
        'from'          =>  $message['from'],
        'subject'       =>  $message['subject'],
        'content'       =>  $message['body'],
        'fromname'      =>  $message['fromname'],
        'tags'          =>  'test',
        'replytoid'     =>  $replyto,
      ),
      'X-APIHEADER' => array('UserID1','UserID2'),
      'settings' => array(
        'footer'        =>  true,
        'clicktrack'    =>  true,
        'opentrack'     =>  true,
      ),
    $response = $email->sendJson( $data );
}

}
```

When I send the mail getting the following error message:

> Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem
>   persists.

User receives the email. What would the reason for the error message be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MailSystemInterface::mail` has a particular return value:

> TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, otherwise FALSE.

The caller uses that to determine whether or not the mail was sent successfully, so just return `TRUE` when the mail succeeds and the error will stop.